# Just in this theorem enumerate are indented

Tags: indentation, enumerate, theorems

I used several unemerate in theorem but just one is intented. I musn't use any indentation in my tex. This statement is wrong:

```
\begin{theorem}
    $(\mathbb{R}_{max},\bigoplus,\bigotimes)$ aşağıdaki özellikleri sağlar.
    \begin{environment}\leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $(\mathbb{R}_{max},\bigoplus)$ bir yarı değişmeli gruptur.
        \item Çarpma işlemi birleşme ve değişmelidir.
        \item Çarpımsal birimi vardır.
        \item $\bigotimes$ işleminin $\bigoplus$ işlemi üzerine dağılma özellikleri vardır. Yani, $x,y,z, \in \mathbb{R}_{max}$ için.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $z\bigotimes(x\bigoplus y)=(z\bigotimes x)\bigoplus(z\bigotimes y)$
            \item $(x\bigoplus y)\bigotimes z = (x\bigotimes z)\bigoplus(y\bigotimes z)$
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Toplamsal birim $-\infty$, çarpma işleminin yutan elemanıdır. Yani $x \in \mathbb{R}_{max}$ için $-\infty \bigotimes x=-\infty = x\bigotimes (-\infty)$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

Another one:

```
\begin{theorem}
$(\mathbb{R}_{max},\bigoplus,\bigotimes)$'da, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{max}$ olamak üzere.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $a^x \bigotimes a^y = a^{x+y}$
    \item $(a^x)^y = a^{x.y}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

---

Now, every list are intended except `\begin{enumerate}[a)]`. Example code: @Bernard

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{report}    %% main class file

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   %% necessary for Turkish characters appeared in Özet

%% Some useful packages, u can remove them or add more
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,epsfig,rawfonts}
\usepackage{theorem,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,natbib}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
%\usepackage{makeidx}    %% use this pack to add an index page
%\makeindex              %% to make an index
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{selcuk1}               %% Style file for Selcuk University

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=3.0cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.0cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=1cm, % Binding offset
    top=2cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
%non-working code:
\begin{theorem}
    $(\mathbb{R}_{max},\bigoplus,\bigotimes)$ aşağıdaki özellikleri sağlar.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $(\mathbb{R}_{max},\bigoplus)$ bir yarı değişmeli gruptur.
        \item Çarpma işlemi birleşme ve değişmelidir.
        \item Çarpımsal birimi vardır.
        \item $\bigotimes$ işleminin $\bigoplus$ işlemi üzerine dağılma özellikleri vardır. Yani, \mbox{$x,y,z, \in \mathbb{R}_{max}$} için.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $z\bigotimes(x\bigoplus y)=(z\bigotimes x)\bigoplus(z\bigotimes y)$
            \item $(x\bigoplus y)\bigotimes z = (x\bigotimes z)\bigoplus(y\bigotimes z)$
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Toplamsal birim $-\infty$, çarpma işleminin yutan elemanıdır. Yani $x \in \mathbb{R}_{max}$ için $-\infty \bigotimes x=-\infty = x\bigotimes (-\infty)$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I have edit your post. Now is more clear.

Comment: What is the `environment` environment?

Comment: When I add environment list numbers don't over theorem.

Comment: ??  I don't understand.

Comment: I used it in this tex another theorem and it didn't affect.

Comment: @amateurboy What should `\begin{environment}\leavevmode` mean?

Comment: In some theorem and proof list number(enumerate) are over theorem or proof. It solves this problem. I can't express myself in english.

Comment: `\leavevmode` is used in case there is no text before the list, to ensure the list begins on its own line, not on the theorem label line. This is not necessary here, as there is some text before the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you want? I loaded `enumitem` and used the `wide=0pt` option. I changed the list labels to upshape, as I think it's nicer in an italic context. It may be set automatically in theorem environments with `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %

 \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}%
 \usepackage{amsthm} \theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}[section]

\usepackage{enumitem}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setlist[enumerate]{font=\em, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}}

\begin{document}%
\setcounter{section}{2}%

\begin{theorem}
    $(\mathbb{R}_{\max},\bigoplus,\bigotimes)$ aşağıdaki özellikleri sağlar.
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item $(\mathbb{R}_{\max},\bigoplus)$ bir yarı değişmeli gruptur.
        \item Çarpma işlemi birleşme ve değişmelidir.
        \item Çarpımsal birimi vardır.
        \item $\bigotimes$ işleminin $\bigoplus$ işlemi üzerine dağılma özellikleri vardır. Yani, $x,y,z, \in \mathbb{R}_{\max}$ için.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $z\bigotimes(x\bigoplus y)=(z\bigotimes x)\bigoplus(z\bigotimes y)$
            \item $(x\bigoplus y)\bigotimes z = (x\bigotimes z)\bigoplus(y\bigotimes z)$
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Toplamsal birim $-\infty$, çarpma işleminin yutan elemanıdır. Yani $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\max}$ için $-\infty \bigotimes x=-\infty = x\bigotimes (-\infty)$
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in my tex. I will try some combination.

Comment: Which distribution do you have, and what does the `.log` file say?

Comment: Miktex 2.9, Texstudio on Windows 10. </br> \begin{theorem} on input line 402 ended by \end{enumerate}. \end{enumerate}

Comment: \begin{document} ended by \end{theorem}. \end{theorem}

Comment: Did you compile the code in my answer??? Your code had a \begin{environment} *not* paired with \end{environment} (undefined anyway) and a `\end{enumerate}` corresponding to no `\begin{enumerate}`. Also, is `enumitem` installed on your system?

Comment: `enumitem` is installed. When I delete `\begin{environment}` nothing change.

Comment: You also had a lonely last \end{enumerate}.

Comment: I just have seen it :). I delete extra `\end{enumerate}` nothing changed. I tryed a lot of combination, there is same statement in same tex but others did work. Now all of them look like it.

Comment: Did you try to compile the code I posted (and only this code)?

Comment: your code is work but `\usepackage{etoolbox}` disrupts the integrity. I want to write every line without indented (equations, tables...).

Comment: hat do you mean by `disrupts the integrity`? I set the case of lists (hopefully). For equations or tables, it's another problem. The case of equations can be set with the`fleqn` option of `amsmath`.  As for tables, if you don't ask explicitly to centre them, they will be left-aligned.

Comment: I use `fleqn` but When I use `\usepackage{etoolbox}` , `fleqn` doesn't work.

Comment: And `enumitem` doesn't work. I can't use `wide` or anything. When I use `wide` it is writen before every item.

Comment: Could you post a minimal non-working code?

Comment: @Bernard - You're an amazingly patient person! Very admirable. Really.